# Decrypting SSL3.3 (SSL3 TLS1.2) with Fiddler4

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, fiddler

I'm working with Delphi and using Indy components for SSL connection. I had Fiddler2 running and was able to see SSL traffic, but had to upgrade Indy to newer version because it had some errors. For compatibility between Indy and OpenSSL I also upgraded to OpenSSL1.0.2a. After this upgrade it seems that it has switched to SSL3.3 a newer protocol than what was used before. I installed Fiddler4.5, .NET framework 4.5 and enabled TLS1.2 as descriped on http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-02-11/fiddler-and-modern-tls-versions. I also reimported Fiddler's certificate to my trusted root certificates, however i can still not decrypt the SSL traffic.

Following is written in Fiddler:
    This is a CONNECT tunnel, through which encrypted HTTPS traffic flows.
    Fiddler's HTTPS Decryption feature is enabled, but this specific tunnel was configured not to be decrypted.  Session Flag 'X-No-Decrypt' was set to: 'PeekYieldedUnknownProtocol'.
    A SSLv3-compatible ServerHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.
    Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)

I tried to search Indy and OpenSSL source for the string "X-No-Decrypt", but it does not seem to be included anywhere. Accoring to fiddlers documentation it seems to be a string that you can include if you dont want fiddler to decrypt this particular session, but i have no idea where this string is included from.

Any suggestions?
Thanks /Rune

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming or development. Perhaps you should try [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The text `PeekYieldedUnknownProtocol` indicates that when Fiddler looked at the first bytes sent by the client within the CONNECT tunnel, those bytes were not those of a HTTPS handshake. To avoid breaking whatever type of traffic is flowing through the tunnel, Fiddler simply passes the bytes back and forth without interpreting them.

To debug this further, your best bet would be to contact me using Help > Send Feedback in Fiddler. If you can send me a SAZ File (File > Save Session Archive) containing the traffic, I can investigate this problem further.

If you *can't* share a SAZ file, please at least right-click on the CONNECT in the Web Sessions list and choose Properties. Update your question with the value of the `x-CONNECT-Peek` flag.